# Nginx Error [1049#0]

Tags: nginx, asterisk

I am using Nginx as Proxy for Websocket SSL upgrade to Asterisk backend.

However at times, my users just couldn't connect to Asterisk. On Asterisk end, I do not see any connection attempt.

Thus I was looking at nginx error log and I found a lot of such error

```
[error] 1049#0: *28726 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 103.246.xx.xx, server: xxx.xxx.io, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://0.0.0.0:8088/ws", host: "yyy.xxx.io"
```

Is there any clue on how can I solve this?

Comment: Some context for the log (not just one line) and your nginx configuration would be most helpfull.

Comment: By the way: you are most probably running out of resources (open files is a usual suspect)

Answer (score 0):

Is this correct? `http://0.0.0.0:8088/ws`

```
In the Internet Protocol version 4 the address 0.0.0.0 is a non-routable
meta-address used to designate an invalid, unknown or non applicable target.
To give a special meaning to an otherwise invalid piece of data is 
an application of in-band signaling.
```

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0

Comment: Yes. Asterisk is hosted at the same server as Nginx.

Comment: @SteveNg the same server is 127.0.0.1 and not 0.0.0.0